# Using Linq to find a very specific pattern from Oracle

Tags: linq, sql-like, contains

I'm replacing a php application using .net and I wish to look for a very specific PATTERN of string in some instances.

I've been using the below code to replace this SQL statement

WHERE FOO LIKE %SMITH%

```
 query = query.Where(x => x.PARTIES.Any(y => y.PNAME.ToUpper().Contains(predicate.PartyName.ToUpper())));
```

This works fine however I've been advised I need to also be able to look for a special pattern like the below

WHERE FOO LIKE %"%SMITH%"%

That would find something like the below.

"CAPTAIN JOHN V.SMITH"

I've attempted to use this code in order to replicate the query but it return 0 hits

```
string s = string.Format("%\"%SMITH%\"%", predicate.PartyName);
query = query.Where(x => x.PARTIES.Any(y => y.PNAME.Contains(s)));
```

Any aid would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this works

```
   query = query.Where(x => x.PARTIES.Any(y => 
       (y.PNAME.StartsWith("\"") 
   && 
       y.PNAME.EndsWith("\"") 
   && 
       y.PNAME.Contains(predicate.PartyName) )));
```